# Raspberry Pi count light values

Tags: python, math

I am working on a science project and I am making a device which can calculate the distance of lightning away from you. I an using a raspberry pi.

I have my code and bredboard set up to count light values using a photo resistor.  I am trying to finish my code by making it count in real time after the light is under a certain value, then it will stop when it hears the "thunder" with a USB mic. Then it will divide the # by 5.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to make it count and then activate a code once it detects the light. 
THIS IS MY CODE

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

__author__ = 'Gus (Adapted from Adafruit)'
__license__ = "GPL"
__maintainer__ = "pimylifeup.com"

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

#define the pin that goes to the circuit
pin_to_circuit = 7

def rc_time (pin_to_circuit):
    count = 0

    #Output on the pin for 
    GPIO.setup(pin_to_circuit, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin_to_circuit, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    #Change the pin back to input
    GPIO.setup(pin_to_circuit, GPIO.IN)

    #Count until the pin goes high
    while (GPIO.input(pin_to_circuit) == GPIO.LOW):
        count += 1

    return count

#Catch when script is interupted, cleanup correctly
try:
    # Main loop
    while True:
        print rc_time (pin_to_circuit)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: why 5?  is that a miles thing?  for kilometers you need to divide by 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of counting in real time could you record the time when each condition occurs and subtract? Something like

```
while True:
  if lightingCondition:
    lightningTime = datetime().time()
    break

while True:
  if thunderCondition:
    thunderTime = datetime().time()
    break

difference = thunderTime - lightningTime
```

Comment: How would I do that if it is an on the spot thing

Comment: And is there a code that can input the time for me, because what you said is the same as doing it in person/ counting in person.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by input the time for you. The whole program should be in a "while True:" loop waiting for the conditions to occur. When they do it will grab the current time from the systems internal clock and compare the two.